# The "gmon.out" file is getting created everywhere

Tags: linux, profiling

Every time I run a program, or exit a shell. There will be a "gmon.out" file generated at the working directory. How to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I have just compiled emacs 24.5 and it creates  "gmon.out" file while exits.
No one option to configure (except of `--without-all`) helped.
This is what helps if no resorting to the `--without-all`:

1. In the file "configure.ac" replace line

   ```
   PROFILING_CFLAGS="-DPROFILING=1 -pg"
   ```

   with the following

   ```
   PROFILING_CFLAGS="-DPROFILING=0 -pg"
   ```
2. Create new "configure" by running command `autoconf`.
3. Use new "configure" for compilation, as usual.

Comment: I don't see any mention of `emacs` in the question ("Every time I run a program, or exit a shell")

Comment: I have the same problem but I do not use emacs. Something keeps on creating gmon.out files. Very annoying. :(

Answer (score 1):

If this is being generated in each and every directory, most probably, your base python was installed with the `--enable-profiling` flag. You can confirm this using:

### Python 3:

```
python3 -m sysconfig -c 'print(sysconfig.get_config_var("CONFIG_ARGS"))'
```

### Python 2:

```
python2 -c "import distutils.sysconfig; print distutils.sysconfig.get_config_vars()"
```

---

Recompiling the same without profiling should resolve the problem.

Comment: forgot about that and it drove me nuts until now ;-) ty!